# How to re-categorize categorical variables more efficiently?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am practicing a dataset, where I have a variable `S6`. It contains 6 levels/factors. The `table` of that variable looks like this:

```
bachelor   values
BBA        291
CSE        10
Math       1
Economics  33
Botany     498
Pharmacy   333
```

I want to re-categorize this variable. Like this:

```
Pharmacy, Botany = Life Science
BBA, CSE, Math, Economics = Others
```

or,

```
Pharmacy, Botany = 1
BBA, CSE, Math, Economics = 2
```

I tried this technique to recategorize this variable:

```
bachelor[S6 %in% c("Pharmacy")] <- "Life Science"
bachelor[S6 %in% c("Botany")] <- "Life Science"
bachelor[S6 %in% c("BBA")] <- "Other"
bachelor[S6 %in% c("CSE")] <- "Other"
bachelor[S6 %in% c("Economics")] <- "Other"
bachelor[S6 %in% c("Math")] <- "Other"
```

This technique actually worked for me. But, it is not practical for a variable that has more than 10 factors or levels.

Please suggest me some more efficient ways to recategorize the categorical variables.

Answer (score 3):

`%in%` function can take more than one variable name on the right side. So you could do:

```
bachelor[S6 %in% c("Pharmacy", "Botany")] <- "Life Science"
bachelor[S6 %in% c("BBA", "CSE", "Economics", "Math")] <- "Other"
```

Alternatively you could create a sort of dictionary for translation and use `match`:

```
dict <- c(Pharmacy="Life Science",
          Botany="Life Science",
          BBA="Other",
          CSE="Other",
          Economics="Other",
          Math="Other")

bachelor <- dict[match(S6, names(dict))]
```

Or, with the use of external package:

```
library(lest)
bachelor <- case_when(S6 %in% c("Pharmacy", "Botany")] ~ "Life Science",
                      S6 %in% c("BBA", "CSE", "Economics", "Math") ~ "Other",
                      TRUE ~ "Rest"
                      )
```

Comment: There's also a ```dplyr::case_when``` that should function the same.

Comment: This is true, `lest` behaves exactly like `dplyr`'s `case_when()`, except has no dependencies.

Comment: Thank you Karolis!